# ember.js - support for number fields

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Does ember provide a number field?

I've tried using the `{{input}}` helper, but it does not seem to accept the html attributes that are specific to number fields.

Suppose I have a `value` property in my controller and this is my template:

```
{{input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value=value}}
```

The `min`, `max` and `step` are ignored.

I also tried:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" {{bind-attr value='value'}}>
```

The attributes now work, but the binding doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure which attributes you want the input field to bind to.

For example:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['size', 'maxlength', 'minlength', 'min', 'max', 'step']
})
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bZy6b/

**Update:** It's no longer required to add the attributeBinding. Ember now automatically binds to size, min, max and step. However, you can still use this method, if you need to bind additional attributes.

**Version 1.4 added min and max:**
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/8eb4e53a478c086d93d2414114e0bd8704237ecc#diff-ef30f4013a02c0c5fceae64680d1899b

**Version 1.5.0-beta.1 added step (and more):**
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/fdfe8495f738c460b0f1595bc8a37a67e568ff0f

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I imagined ember had something like an `Ember.NumberField`, for internal use.

Comment: I believe that now you can just do this `{{input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1"}}` and not have to reopen TextField and add the attribute bindings.

Comment: Good catch. It looks like it's fixed in more recent versions of Ember. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/895ebcf2824b36b1fdf850811b47cc142e970668/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L34. I've updated the answer.